# Titanium Android - Failed to compile Java source files

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an android app compiled with SDK 7.4.0.GA. I'm trying to update it (to 8.3.1.GA) but, during the compilation, I have this error message, with 2 [ERROR] empty :

```
[ERROR] Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]
```

I tried to create a new app project, but the problem is the same. I also tried with 7.5.2.GA, and I still have this error.
I have run 'ti clean', with no effect.

If I execute 'ti info', it says 'Unable to locate an Android NDK', but I would need it also with 7.4.0, so I think it's not the problem ?

Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: is that the whole output of `ti info` or is it just one of the errors? It would be good to see the installed versions of your toolchain (javac, node, titanium, alloy, appc, Android SDKs). You could also increase your JAVA memory `ti android.javac.maxMemory "1G"` and `ti config android.dx.maxMemory "1G"` and compile it with `-l trace` to see some more logs.

Comment: It was because of the memory :o
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Nice, I'll add it as an answer so other people can find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase your JAVA memory

```
ti config android.javac.maxMemory "1G"
ti config android.dx.maxMemory "1G"
```

and check your `ti info` with `-l trace`

Comment: You forgot the "config" for the first command, in the comment and in the answer :)